# Firefox: See what modified my HTTP headers

Tags: firefox, http-headers, http-accept-language

How can I find out what part of my Firefox installation modifies my HTTP headers?

Using [a tool that displays my headers for the corresponding request](https://martin.christianix.de/headers.php) I can see my headers contain the following string:

`Accept-Language: de,ar-SA;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3`

I want to find out how ar-SA got in there.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you'd go about seeing what changed your HTTP headers specifically, but I do know where you set your preferred languages. In Preferences, go to the Language section:

[image: Firefox Language Section]

And then click on "Choose..." to see them:

[image: Firefox Preferred Languages Menu]

I added "Dutch [nl]" to mine to see if my headers would change and sure enough they did:

```
Accept-Language: nl,en-GB;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
```

Comment: Thanks, this answers how I can see my preferences and indeed ar-SA is in there. However I'd like to know how it got in there!